# Compile gvim from sources?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, gvim, compile

Recently, I've installed `vim` like so:

```
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
cd vim
sudo ./configure --enable-rubyinterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-gui=gtk2 --prefix=/opt/vim
make 
make install
make install clean
```

So, my VIM's binaries now live under `/opt/vim/bin`. Here is `ls -la` of this dir:

```
$ ls -la /opt/vim/bin
total 1500
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 2011-05-25 12:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 2011-05-25 12:46 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       3 2011-05-25 12:46 ex -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       3 2011-05-25 12:46 rview -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       3 2011-05-25 12:46 rvim -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       3 2011-05-25 12:46 view -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1504188 2011-05-25 12:46 vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       3 2011-05-25 12:46 vimdiff -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2084 2011-05-25 12:46 vimtutor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   13900 2011-05-25 12:46 xxd
```

Where is my `vim.gtk`? I specified `--enable-gui=gtk2` in configure. Shouldn't it say the installer I want a GUI version as well as console application?

I specified `gtk` version correctly:

```
$ dpkg -l libgtk[0-9]* | grep ^i
ii  libgtk2-perl                          1:1.221-4                                  Perl interface to the 2.x series of the Gimp Toolkit library
ii  libgtk2.0-0                           2.18.3-1ubuntu2.2                          The GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-bin                         2.18.3-1ubuntu2.2                          The programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-common                      2.18.3-1ubuntu2.2                          Common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
```

**UPDATE**:
It is written on src/INSTALL

```
 88 Unix: COMPILING WITH/WITHOUT GUI
 89
 90 NOTE: This is incomplete, look in Makefile for more info.
 91
 92 These configure arguments can be used to select which GUI to use:
 93 --enable-gui=gtk      or: gtk2, motif, athena or auto
 94 --disable-gtk-check
 95 --disable-motif-check
 96 --disable-athena-check
 97
 98 --enable-gui defaults to "auto", so it will automatically look for a GUI (in
 99 the order of GTK, Motif, then Athena).  If one is found, then is uses it and
100 does not proceed to check any of the remaining ones.  Otherwise, it moves on
101 to the next one.
```

So I tried not to specify `--enable-gui` hoping it will find which GUI engine/toolkit to use on its own... Still the same result :(

**UPDATE**:
Furthermore:

```
/opt/vim/bin$ ./vim -g
E25: GUI cannot be used: Not enabled at compile time
```

**UPDATE**:

Do I need ALL of this:

```
$ sudo aptitude search gtk | grep dev
p   gnunet-gtk-dev                  - secure, trust-based peer-to-peer framework
v   gtkgl-dev                       -                                           
p   gtkparasite                     - GTK+ debugging and development tool       
p   libaiksaurusgtk-1.2-dev         - graphical interface to the Aiksaurus toolk
v   libaiksaurusgtk-dev             -                                           
p   libcanberra-gtk-dev             - a simple abstract interface for playing ev
p   libchamplain-gtk-0.4-dev        - A Gtk+ widget to display maps (development
p   libclutter-gtk-0.10-dev         - Open GL based interactive canvas library G
p   libdbusmenu-gtk-dev             - Menus over DBus shared library for GTK    
p   libempathy-gtk-dev              - High-level library and user-interface for 
v   libequeue-gtk2-ocaml-dev        -                                           
p   libexif-gtk-dev                 - Library providing GTK+ widgets to display/
p   libgalago-gtk-dev               - libraries and header files for developing 
p   libgdu-gtk-dev                  - GTK+ standard dialog library for libgdu - 
p   libggadget-gtk-1.0-dev          - Google Gadgets GTK+ development files     
p   libggz-gtk-dev                  - GGZ Gaming Zone: core client embedding lib
p   libghc6-gtk-dev                 - A GUI library for Haskell (Gtk2Hs) -- GTK+
p   libghc6-gtkglext-dev            - A GUI library for Haskell (Gtk2Hs) -- gtkg
p   libghc6-gtksourceview2-dev      - A GUI library for Haskell (Gtk2Hs) -- GtkS
p   libghc6-soegtk-dev              - A GUI library for Haskell (Gtk2Hs) -- soeg
p   libglrr-gtk-dev                 - Development library of Grift (gtk)        
p   libgpod-nogtk-dev               - development files for libgpod (version wit
p   libgtk-directfb-2.0-dev         - Development files for the GTK+ library - D
p   libgtk-vnc-1.0-dev              - A VNC viewer widget for GTK+ (development
i   libgtk2.0-dev                   - Development files for the GTK+ library
p   libgtkada2-dev                  - Development files for libgtkada2
p   libgtkdatabox-0.9.0-1-dev       - A Gtk+ library to display large amounts of
v   libgtkdatabox-dev               -
p   libgtkextra-x11-2.0-dev         - A useful set of widgets for GTK+ (developm
p   libgtkgl2.0-dev                 - OpenGL area for GTK (development files)
p   libgtkglext1-dev                - OpenGL Extension to GTK+ (development file
p   libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev       - C++ bindings for GtkGLExt (Development fil
p   libgtkhex0-dev                  - GNOME Hex editor for files (development he
p   libgtkhtml-editor-dev           - HTML rendering/editing library - editor wi
p   libgtkhtml2-dev                 - HTML rendering/editing library - developme
p   libgtkhtml3.14-dev              - HTML rendering/editing library - developme
p   libgtkhtml3.8-dev               - HTML rendering/editing library - developme
p   libgtkimageview-dev             - image viewer widget for GTK+ (development
p   libgtkmathview-dev              - rendering engine for MathML documents
p   libgtkmm-2.4-dev                - C++ wrappers for GTK+ 2.4 (development fil
p   libgtkmm-utils-dev              - utility functions, classes and widgets wri
p   libgtksourceview-dev            - development files for the GTK+ syntax high
p   libgtksourceview2.0-dev         - development files for the GTK+ syntax high
p   libgtksourceviewmm-1.0-dev      - C++ binding of GtkSourceView - development
p   libgtksourceviewmm-2.0-dev      - C++ binding of GtkSourceView - development
p   libgtkspell-dev                 - Development files for GtkSpell
p   libindicate-gtk-dev             - GNOME panel indicator applet - shared libr
p   libjana-gtk-dev                 - A set of GTK+ widgets to visualise libjana
p   liblablgtk2-gl-ocaml-dev        - OCaml bindings to GtkGL
p   liblablgtk2-gnome-ocaml-dev     - OCaml bindings to GNOME
p   liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev           - OCaml bindings to Gtk+ version 2
p   liblablgtkmathview-ocaml-dev    - OCaml bindings for libgtkmathview, a GTK w
p   liblablgtksourceview-ocaml-dev  - OCaml bindings for libgtksourceview, a sou
v   libnotify-dev-gtk2.10           -
p   libocamlnet-gtk2-ocaml-dev      - OCaml application-level Internet libraries
p   libpolkit-gtk-1-dev             - PolicyKit GTK+ API - development files
v   libsylpheed-claws-gtk2-dev      -
p   libtinymailui-gtk-dev           - Framework for mobile applications with e-m
p   libtinymailui-gtkhtml-dev       - Framework for mobile applications with e-m
p   libtracker-gtk-dev              - GTK+ widgets for apps that use tracker - d
v   libunicapgtk-dev                -
p   libunicapgtk2-dev               - graphical widgets for unicap - development
p   libwxgtk2.6-dev                 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (
p   libwxgtk2.8-dev                 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (
p   libzbargtk-dev                  - scanning and decoding bar codes (GTK+ bind
p   python-galago-gtk-dev           - Galago presence library (Python interface)
p   python-gtk2-dev                 - GTK+ bindings: devel files
p   telepathy-devel-gtk             - Telepathy Development packages for GTK
```

Looks like most of ths packages I don't need. E.g. Frameworks for mobile apps, ... HTML renderers, etc. The one I've installed is `libgtk2.0-dev`... Still, I can't compile `gVIM`.... Agrhhhhh

Comment: Why are you doing "sudo ./configure [...]"?  The configure script should not need to be run as root.  I can understand doing "sudo make isntall", although you don't need to do "make install" and then "make install clean" as that would install Vim twice—just do "make install; make clean".

Comment: You shouldn't need to install a bunch of random dev files. If the configure script can't find the libraries it needs, **it will refuse to output a makefile.**. Seems like your issue is with `configure` itself. I'd check `config.log`, and see how it handles the `--enable-gui` option, etc.

Comment: Similar on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132724/how-do-i-compile-the-latest-gvim-from-source

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem installing gvim 7.3 onto Centos 6.2 (x86_64)

Some required devel packages were missing. To install them:

`yum groupinstall "Desktop Platform Development"`

[To view all available groups: `yum grouplist`]

Then building from source just worked

```
wget ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.3.tar.bz2
bunzip2 vim-7.3.tar.bz2
tar xf vim-7.3.tar
cd vim73

./configure --prefix=/home/me/vim73
make
make install
```

To discover what files were missing:

```
./configure | less
```

and searching for 'gui' showed that X11 related headers were missing.

Answer (score 6):

In **ubuntu** I compile vim the following way:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vim
sudo apt-get build-dep libx11-dev libxtst-dev

make distclean

./configure --with-compiledby="David Gamba <davidgamba@gambaeng.com>" \
--with-features=huge \
--enable-gui=auto \
--with-x \
--enable-rubyinterp \
--with-ruby-command=/usr/bin/ruby \
--enable-perlinterp \
--enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
--enable-fontset \
--enable-cscope \
--enable-gtk2-check \
--enable-gnome-check

make
```

At this point, `cd src` and check for the correct X11 and clipboard support: `./vim --version`. Then:

```
sudo make install
```

For **Fedora** (using the KDE desktop) I installed the following packages:

```
yum install gcc libX11-devel libXtst-devel ncurses-devel perl-ExtUtils-Embed ruby ruby-devel python-devel gtk2-devel libXt-devel
```

And changed my configure command to the following:

```
./configure --with-compiledby="David Gamba <davidgamba@gambaeng.com>" \
--with-features=huge \
--enable-gui=auto \
--with-x \
--enable-rubyinterp \
--with-ruby-command=/usr/bin/ruby \
--enable-perlinterp \
--enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python2.7/config \
--enable-fontset \
--enable-cscope \
--enable-gtk2-check \
--enable-gnome-check \
--enable-fail-if-missing
```

After that I get the following:

```
gvim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled May  4 2014 19:43:27)
Included patches: 1-274
Compiled by David Gamba <davidgamba ...>
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that for **Fedora** I was getting an error with the location of the `xsubpp` perl script so I ended up modifying the Makefile thanks to some bug report online.

```
--- a/src/Makefile      Fri May 02 15:46:14 2014 +0200
+++ b/src/Makefile      Sun May 04 19:56:20 2014 -0600
@@ -2465,7 +2465,7 @@

 auto/if_perl.c: if_perl.xs
        $(PERL) -e 'unless ( $$] >= 5.005 ) { for (qw(na defgv errgv)) { print "#define PL_$$_ $$_\n" }}' > $@
-       $(PERL) $(PERLLIB)/ExtUtils/xsubpp -prototypes -typemap \
+       $(PERL) /usr/bin/xsubpp -prototypes -typemap \
            $(PERLLIB)/ExtUtils/typemap if_perl.xs >> $@

  auto/osdef.h: auto/config.h osdef.sh osdef1.h.in osdef2.h.in
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to find necessary dependencies for gvim:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vim
```

If you haven't add source repository in your source.list file in /etc/apt/, you can open this file, duplicate the entries inside and change "dep" to "dep-src".

After all dependencies installed, you will be able to compile vim with gui.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the case of not having enough `*-devel` packages installed. Try installing all the devel packages. I think there is a meta-package for installing most of them. Try `gnome-devel`. Sorry I don't have Ubuntu nearby right now.

To compile different variants of vim (e.g. GUI and non-GUI), you have to configure/compile it multiple times.

Comment: On Unix-like systems, there is no reason to build separate GUI and non-GUI versions. A "normal" build and install will create a single binary named `vim` to which all the other forms of Vim--`gvim`, `view`, `ex`, etc.--are linked. Vim knows which personality to adopt based on the name by which it was invoked.

Comment: You're right, you don't *have* to. But most distros do have separate builds for GUI and non-GUI variants, available in different binary packages. Something like a `minimal` and a `full featured` version. The OP seemed to want to also do that.

Comment: I'm on KDE, so I'm actually have **K**Ubuntu

Comment: That said, I agree with Keith that it looks like you're missing some development packages. There's an apt-get command that will install build dependencies of a specified target, but I don't have an Ubuntu system handy at the moment, either.

Comment: Even so, you wanted the gtk+ GUI build, so you will need all the gtk devel packages installed. the gnome-devel is a meta package that will pull of of them in. Their might be a smaller, gtk specific one. But I can't check right now.

Comment: I've installed gtk2-dev. Nothing changed. Now I do all this process again and outputing result of `sudo ./configure --enable-rubyinterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-gui=gtk2 --prefix=/opt/vim` to file for closer look after.

Comment: I have updated my question :)

Comment: Check the config.log and see what it says about GUI selection.

Answer (score 1):

I also failed to build vim73 with enable-gui option on RHEL6.1 due to lack of *X11/Intrinsic.h*.
Did your linux have the include file?
If not, you could get it from, I guess, the **libxt-dev** package.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the output when you're compiling vim. I haven't compiled vim myself but I'm pretty sure there'll be some warnings/errors regarding missing files needed for gvim.

Comment: Unfortunately when it tells you you are missing something it doesn't tell you which package provides that or what is the name of the providing library, so that is why you need to give a bit more than that.